# How was the isoperimetric inequality formulated?

Tags: geometry, inequality, math-history

I'm tyring to understand how the isoperimetric inequality came into existence.
It seems like finding the region which yields maximum area when enclosed by a curve of fixed length
is an old problem. [Queen Dido](http://mathematicalgarden.wordpress.com/2008/12/21/the-problem-of-dido/) seems to have figured out the solution a long time ago: that the region should be a circle.

I'm currently reading how [Steiner's method](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:L1N3KTkitrAJ:www.cs.nyu.edu/faculty/siegel/SCIAM.pdf+history+of+isoperimetric+inequality&hl=en&gl=za&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEEShec-ilirIfxQ0ze3cy_eZv6LPEZfuuxkZbjc9dOa4kFX0oB5-I5Mjyo6cACnehXfkM1vqXH2AvEFOndoEx9Q1sUTOWg8Y62ncX-fnXep_vX2xt5xQv4GzSDVwNugCvkEhZ3VHw&sig=AHIEtbRA5ahtD6AqkZMWc64hjIzL3SmvbA) of characterizing how certain regions
cannot yield maximum area.

My question however is that how was the following inequality formulated:

> $4\pi A\leq L^2$

where $A$ is the area of the region which we will be considering and $L$ is the length of the curve which encloses it.

I understand we are trying to find a relationship between the area of the region and the length of the curve. I expect the area to be a function of the length perhaps ($A$~$f(L)$ where ~ represents some relation). In this case it happens that we have $A \leq \frac{1}{4\pi}L^2$

My question is simply -- why?

**EDIT**

Given a region $\mathbb{L}$ with $A=Area(\mathbb{L})$ and a curve with a fixed length of $L$

why do we have that $4\pi A\leq L^2$ ?

Comment: If you believe that the optimal curve is a circle then surely you can figure out the relationship between its area and circumference yourself.

Comment: Are you saying that inequality is purely based on the circle?

If so, what you're saying doesn't make sense as the isoperimetric inequality only says that the region is a circle if $A=\frac{1}{4\pi}L^2$

Comment: For fixed length the circle has the maximum area $\iff$ for fixed length no curve has more area than the circle $\iff$ for fixed length no curve has area more than $\frac1{4\pi}L^2$ $\iff$ $A\le\frac1{4\pi}L^2$. Of course, to prove the premise that the circle has the maximum area, you have the whole rest of the proof of the isoperimetric inequality.